# Have Windows 8 Pro, still need to uninstall Consumer Preview

Tags: windows-8, bootloader

A few months ago, I tried to install the Consumer Preview, but something went wrong, it failed, and I continued with Windows 7. However, I did notice I now had a dual boot menu at startup, asking me which OS to use. Consumer Preview was corrupt so I just continued with 7.

Today, I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 8 Pro and decided to do a clean install without reformatting. However, the Consumer Preview fragment is still on my computer and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You will have to locate the files on the hdd if they exist and just remove the boot.ini.

Comment: Where would they be? Somewhere in the Windows folder I assume, but I don't know where after.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the entry from the boot menu by using msconfig. To do this:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> to open the Start Screen and type `msconfig`:

   [image: Searching for msconfig]
2. Launch it as an Administrator by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. If prompted whether to run as an Administrator click `Yes`
3. Switch to the `Boot` tab:

   [image: Boot tab]
4. Select the entry you wish to delete and click `Delete`

Note that this will not remove any files associated with the failed installation - I would need more information than you have provided for that and it is a more dangerous operation to complete. I will be happy to go through this if you wish.

Comment: This will remove a boot prompt, but won't remove any partition that might have been created or files (such as a Windows.000 folder) that might have been created.

Comment: That's why I explained that in my last paragraph ;)